# Use of Tabu search Algorithm for solving optimization problem

Tags: optimization, heuristics

I am trying to solve a maximization problem using the Tabu search algorithm but there is no relevant code available on the internet. Any kind of sample code is highly appreciable.

My function is F(x)= x^3-60.x^2+90.x, 0 < x < 31

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this task? Why do you insist on using Tabu search?  That doesn't seem like the best algorithm for this task. Requests for code are off-topic here.  Tabu search is documented in many standard places; what research have you done?

Comment: I understand later that this algorithm is not suitable for solving this function. I can see that this Tabu search generally used for solving the Travelling Salesman Problem and so on.